# Как создать такую форму на yii2?

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, yii2

Здравствуйте. Есть вот такая форма с кучей радио кнопок. В каждом блоке своя группа радио кнопок. Они должны создаваться динамически на основе данных из БД и группироваться по просмотрам. Для каждого года свой блок.

**Вопрос**: каким образом можно данный html перевести в валидный код для yii2? И как грамотно организовать модель для обработки данных с этих форм?

```css
.ThisDay-default-index {
  position: relative;
}

.horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.control-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 275px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}

.thisday-container {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.control {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.control input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.control__indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.control--radio .control__indicator {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.control:hover input~.control__indicator,
.control input:focus~.control__indicator {
  background: #ccc;
}

.control input:checked~.control__indicator {
  background: #2aa1c0;
}

.control:hover input:not([disabled]):checked~.control__indicator,
.control input:checked:focus~.control__indicator {
  background: #0e647d;
}

.control input:disabled~.control__indicator {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.control__indicator:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.control input:checked~.control__indicator:after {
  display: block;
}

.control--radio .control__indicator:after {
  left: 7px;
  top: 7px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.control--radio input:disabled~.control__indicator:after {
  background: #7b7b7b;
}

#thisday-resume {
  position: absolute;
  right: 45%;
  top: 0%;
}

.control-views-count {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.thisday-butt {
  float: right;
}

.thisday-time {
  float: left;
}

.thisday-content {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="ThisDay-default-index">
  <div class="form-group thisday-butt">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Далее</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="thisday-time">Выберите ключевые новости
    12 Января из прошлого:</p>
  <form class="thisday-content" action="thisday-edit.php" method="post">
    <!-- <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-default">Далее</button> -->
    <div class="thisday-container">
      <div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper">
        <div class="control-group">
          <h3>2016</h3>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio1"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      <span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio1"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio1">
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio1">
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <h3>2015</h3>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio2"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio2"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio2">
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio2">
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <h3>2014</h3>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio3"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio3"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio3">
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio3">
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <h3>2013</h3>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio4"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio4"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio4">
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio4">
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <h3>2012</h3>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio5"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio5"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio5">
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio5">
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <h3>2011</h3>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio6"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio6"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio6">
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
          <label class="control control--radio">Заголовок новости длииииииииииииный
      <input type="radio" name="radio6">
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
<span class="control-views-count">1500</span>
    </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Смотреть пример лучше на всю страницу :)

Comment: Я бы помог вам, но вы не показали структуру бд или модели данных. К сожалению, лично я могу ответить на этот вопрос только готовым рабочим кодом, потому что ничего необычного тут нет. Читайте про ActiveForm. Можно легко использовать этот компонент

Comment: @ilyaplot каким образом мне нужно дополнить свой вопрос, чтобы опираясь на информацию из него Вы смогли как то помочь?

Comment: Создайте модели для ваших данных, view, попробуйте построить форму. Если что-то не получится, показывайте, что вышло, будем помогать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Результат]

Работа с данными:

```
/**
 * Допустим, новости хранятся в таблице article с полями id, title, views и year
 */
class Article extends \yii\base\Model //\yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    // Я добавил поля в модель и наследовал \yii\base\Model потому, что не работаю с бд
    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $views;
    public $year;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return "article";
    }
}

/**
 * $articles = Article::find()
 * // Сортируем по году и ID
 * ->orderBy(['year' => SORT_DESC, 'id' => SORT_ASC])
 * // Массив будет такого вида: [2017 => [Article, Article, ....], 2018 => [...]]
 * ->indexBy('year')
 * ->all();
 */

// У меня такой таблиц нет, я просто эмулирую выборку

$articles = [
    2016 => [
        new Article([
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => "Test title",
            'views' => 100500,
            'year' => 2016
        ]),
        new Article([
            'id' => 2,
            'title' => "Test title 2",
            'views' => 1000,
            'year' => 2016
        ]),
        new Article([
            'id' => 3,
            'title' => "Title for 3",
            'views' => 200,
            'year' => 2016
        ]),
    ],
    2017 => [
        new Article([
            'id' => 4,
            'title' => "Test title 2017",
            'views' => 100500,
            'year' => 2017
        ]),
        new Article([
            'id' => 5,
            'title' => "Test title 2017 2",
            'views' => 0,
            'year' => 2017
        ]),
        new Article([
            'id' => 6,
            'title' => "Title for 2017 3",
            'views' => 800,
            'year' => 2017
        ]),
    ]
];
```

View:

```
<div class="ThisDay-default-index">
    <div class="form-group thisday-butt">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Далее</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="thisday-time">Выберите ключевые новости
        12 Января из прошлого:</p>
    <?php
    $form = \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin([
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'thisday-content',
        ],
    ]); ?>
    <div class="thisday-container">
        <div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper">
            <?php foreach ($articles as $year => $yearArticles): ?>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <h3><?= $year ?></h3>

                    <?php foreach ($yearArticles as $article): ?>

                        <?= $form->field($article, 'id[' . $year . '][]')->radio([
                            'value' => $article->id,
                            'label' => \app\helpers\Html::encode($article->title)
                                . \app\helpers\Html::tag('div', '', ['class' => 'control__indicator'])
                                . \app\helpers\Html::tag('span', $article->views, ['class' => 'control-views-count']),
                            'labelOptions' => [
                                'encode' => false,
                                'class' => 'control control--radio',
                            ],
                        ]); ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание на атрибут модели. Я сделал так, что бы radio работали внутри одного года. input будет содержать такие параметры: `name="Article[id][2017][]" value="4"`. В POST будет массив `['Article' => ['id' => [5, 6]]]`
Если выбрать значение можно только для одного года, то можно убрать год из аттрибута

Comment: Этот вариант позволит использовать все прелести ActiveForm, такие как ajax валидация, csrf защита и прочее.

Comment: Обработка данных - это уже второй вопрос. На него я ответить пока не могу, потому что не сказано, как вообще их хотите обрабатывать. Но там точно ничего сложного быть не должно. Получите массив айдишников.

Comment: С обработкой данных это отдельный вопрос, это правда) Я просто только начал изучать yii2 и сразу на рабочей задаче поэтому даже не знал чего я не знал) Ваш код очень нагляден, мне потребуется время чтобы осознать его, но кажется что это то, что мне было нужно) Касательно радио кнопок - для каждого года мне потребуется только один инпут, поэтому год в массиве все же нужно оставить, т.к далее я помещу его в следущее представление вместе с заголовком

Comment: а правильно ли работу с данными проводить в модели модуля? Или это нужно делать в контроллере?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев Зависит от того, что называть работой с данными. В идеале контроллер должен получить данные от пользователя и отправить их в модель. Если логика обработки данных болшьшая или будет существовать несколько больших сценариев, то следует создать модель - прослойку, а не нагружать основную модель тяжелой логикой. Возможно, в вашем случае хватит возможностей AR, но это не точно :)

Comment: я собираюсь формировать многомерный массив следующим запросом
SELECT `id`, `name`, FROM_UNIXTIME(`cdate_int`), `id_author` FROM `news` WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(cdate_int, "%d") = текущая дата AND FROM_UNIXTIME(cdate_int, "%m") = текущий месяц AND id_region = регион пользователя
И на основании результата выдачи формировать многомерный массив где ключом будет год новости. Вот что я пытался Вам тогда сказать, но моих знаний в тот момент категорически не хватало для этого)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев Я бы сделал статический метод модели, который реализует выборку с группировкой.

Comment: так все таки работать с моделью а не с контроллером? Просто я подключаю модель News и из нее выбираю данные через ::find();

Comment: Лучше с моделью